# Ember.RSVP.hash and acceptance testing

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I have a hash that's called from a service:

```
return new Ember.RSVP.hash({
    locations: ajax(
      {
            url: applicationConfig.apiUrl + '/api/v1/locations/search?term=' + term
      }),
    listingEvents: ajax({
            url: applicationConfig.apiUrl + '/api/v1/listingevents/search?term=' + term 
      })
  });
```

Now in my tests I am getting:

```
✘ Error: Assertion Failed: You have turned on testing mode, which disabled the run-loop's autorun.
                  You will need to wrap any code with asynchronous side-effects in a run
```

I have wrapped the hash in an `Ember.run` but that doesn't work.

What is the best way to get the hash to run in acceptance tests?

Comment: Where you call .then from the resulting promise, inside there you must wrap code in Ember.run.

Comment: Hmmm tried that and it's still complaining :/

Comment: RSVP.hash is not a constructor. You don't need the new. Not sure if related tho.

Comment: Removed the ```new``` and still getting the same fail :/